# i can't call a number in android api23

Tags: android, android-activity, permissions

i al trying to call a number but the permisson check is false, so the method retuns and i get nothing.

code method:

```
public void call(String s) {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+s));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(),     Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        System.out.println("fout bellen");
        return;
    }
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

it gives me the system.out.println "fout bellen" every time i click on my Relative Layout(on click listener)

all help is welcome.

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to request runtime permission like this.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
```

So your code will be like this

```
private static final int REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1;
public void call(String s) {       
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(),     
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                        REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
                 return;
    }
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+s));
    startActivity(callIntent);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PHONE_CALL : {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+s));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: he doesn't find "REQUEST_CALL_PHONE"